# Send amount to sellers bank account from stripe account in php

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, stripe-connect

I have to send the sellers amount in his bank account or card . Seller doesn't containing any stripe account.How can i send the amount in seller bank account from my stripe account(Admin Account)?

I am using this code: And not understanding what is "CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID". I have to send money in his bank account not his stripe account.

Can somebody help?
// Create a Transfer to a connected account (later):

```
$transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create(array(
  "amount" => 7000,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "destination" => "{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}",
  "transfer_group" => "{ORDER10}",
));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not send funds to a bank account or debit card directly like this. Instead, the seller needs to create a Stripe Account. The idea is to use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) and ask your seller to either sign up for their own Stripe account or you would create one for them behind the scenes. This is documented in details [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/connecting-to-accounts).

Once they have their account, you will be able to create one of those transfers or create a charge on their behalf. There are multiple solutions to this depending on your business model and who you want to pay Stripe's fees or hold liability. Those methods are described in details [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges#choosing-approach).

Comment: $account = \Stripe\Account::create(array("country" => "US", managed" => false,"email" => $chkuser['email'],"external_account" => array("object" => "bank_account", "account_number" => $params['account_number'], "country" => "US","currency" => "usd",  "routing_number" => $params['routing_number'],
                        "account_holder_type" => "individual",
                        "account_holder_name" => $params['name']
                    )
                ));
Is this right way to create?And will he get sent amount in his account now?

Comment: $transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create(array(
            "amount" => 10,
            "currency" => "usd",
            "destination" => "acct_1AD8bAEnY4Utpb4c",
            "transfer_group" => "ORDER_95"
        ))
After account creation i send amount like this . is this the right method?

Comment: @Prince that works yes. I'd recommend spending some time reading the documentation to fully understand Connect and then you should be able to do everything you need.

Comment: OK Thanks! i will defiantly spent more time on that.